# Sntp.sync() ignores server

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I've been trying to synchronize time with ntp servers, however, nodemcu seems to ignore the server parameter.

```
-- sync.lua
sntp.sync("fr.pool.ntp.org", function()
  tm = rtctime.epoch2cal(rtctime.get())
  print(string.format("%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", tm["year"], tm["mon"], tm["day"], tm["hour"], tm["min"], tm["sec"]))
end)
```

Execution..

```
> dofile('sync.lua')
> 2017/05/22 21:38:39
```

The time response is the unix epoch time (https://www.epochconverter.com/). Is it supposed to be the server parameter time (in this case, France)? I tried several different servers (i.e http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/europe) but the response stills the same.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: No, Epoch time is UTC. You will have to apply time zones to the result to get local time. I'm not sure what is available in your environment that could do that for you, but France is 2 hours ahead of UTC.

Comment: @ktb so... why is allowed to ntp server as parameter if it returns always the UTC time?

Comment: You do want your time fix to be accurate, right? Well, if you live in France, you want a French server, not a Japanese server to tell you the time. One's quite a bit farther from your place of residence.

Comment: @ktb I want to get the time of the sntp server passed as parameter. I was wondering if I use a sntp french server, I would get the french time. However, this is not happening. It always returns the unix time. The question is: is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. No matter where you get the time from, it's always UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is correct. If you want to work with timezones you need so called ["zone files" from the tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). Each tz file contains (amongst other info) transitions such as daylight saving time, and it also records leap seconds.

There's an example of how to deal with [timezones in the NodeMCU repository](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/tree/master/lua_examples/timezone).

```
tz = require('tz')
tz.setzone('eastern')
sntp.sync(nil, function(now)
  local tm = rtctime.epoch2cal(now + tz.getoffset(now))
  print(string.format("%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", tm["year"], tm["mon"], tm["day"], tm["hour"], tm["min"], tm["sec"]))
end)
```

So, you need [`tz.lua`](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/lua_examples/timezone/tz.lua) plus the zone file(s) for the timezone(s) you're interested in ('eastern' in the example).