# NodeMCU Time zone based SNTP synchronization

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I have an ESP8266 NodeMCU board. I have loaded the NodeMCU Lua based firmware on it and need accurate time keeping for scheduling few functions. I built the binary using their cloud service with following modules: `rtctime`, `sntp`, `cron` amongst others.

How can I set the local time using `sntp` module? My local time has an offset of 19800 (5.5 hours IST) from UTC.

I am unable to set this offset in `sntp.setoffset(offset)` call

```
> sntp.setoffset(19800)
> sntp.getoffset()
88
>
```

why does `getoffset` print `88`?

Update: Setting the RTC to local time by using `rtctime.set(seconds_since_unix_epoch)` in the success callback of `sntp.sync()` works fine.

```
function sntp_sync_time()
  sntp.sync(nil, function(sec, usec, server, info) rtctime.set(sec + 19800) end, sntp_sync_time, 1)
end
```

Also I'm calling the same function recursively in the failure callback until successful synchronization doesn't happen.

Thanks

Comment: Could it be that your huge offset of 5.5h indicates that you're (ab)using the SNTP offset for timezone handling? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44142782/131929 for an example.

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm doing this to handle time zones. But I see that you have added the time zone offset in the success callback(in your linked answer), so does that mean RTC will be in sync with UTC and not the timezone? Or do I still have to do `rtctime.set(now+tz.getoffset(now))` in the success callback?

Comment: I don't know but I'd say SNTP and RTCtime should be left alone to deal with UTC internally. Timezone adjustments i.e. UTC-to-timezone conversion should be done _outside_ those modules like we propose in our example (that I replicated in that answer).

Comment: @MarcelStör thanks. I guess I'll have to add offsets every time I'm using the RTC to schedule something. I'll update the question and mark this as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Seems odd.
The least significant byte of 19800 (01001101 01011000) is 88 (01011000).

I am not that familiar with Lua and it's bindings to C, but I checked the source and found that the [`setoffset`](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/2.1.0-master_20170521/app/modules/sntp.c#L591-L604) and [`getoffset`](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/2.1.0-master_20170521/app/modules/sntp.c#L606-L612) work with the [variable `the_offest` which is defined as `uint8_t`](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/2.1.0-master_20170521/app/modules/sntp.c#L143).

<s>Because [the docs](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/sntp/#sntpsetoffset) say, the offset is in number of seconds and a byte is too small, I would say this is a bug.</s>

As it was explained in the comments by Marcel Stör, `sntp.setoffset` isn't meant for timezone offsets, which means that big offsets aren't supported.
You should use the [tz module](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/tree/master/lua_examples/timezone) to handle timezones.

Comment: Woah, clever analysis of the correlation between 19800 and 88 \*applause\*

Comment: @gre_gor Thanks for pointing out the 88 cause.